# How to use custom domain on Heroku with Parse Server?

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-server

A Parse Server is hosted on Heroku at `myapp.herokuapps.com`.

The Heroku app has a custom domain `example.com`. The domain has the CNAME record `myapp.herokuapps.com`.

Connecting the Parse iOS SDK works for the endpoints:

```
https://myapp.herokuapps.com/parse
http://myapp.herokuapps.com/parse
http://example.com/parse
```

But it does not work for

```
https://example.com/parse
```

The Xcode console shows the error:

```
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (Code: 100, Version: ...)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9838)
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a TSL certificate to the Heroku app. If you have a paid dyno the certificate is available at no extra cost.

> All applications with paid dynos include ACM for free.

1. Open Heroku app in Heroku dashboard
2. Open Settings tab
3. In section `Domains and certificates` click `Configure SSL` and choose `Automatically configure using Automated Certificate Management`.
4. Click `Add domain` to add the domain from which the request should be forwarded, e.g. `api.example.com`.
5. On your domain registrar's website set the `CNAME` for `api.example.com` to the domain in the Heroku app settings, e.g. `api.example.com.herokudns.com`
6. Wait until the status of the domain in the Heroku dashboard is `Done`

Works.

Answer (score -1):

You have to buy an SSL cert for the domain, which Heroku upcharges like crazy. It's gonna be like $200 / mo. or something ridiculous, but you really should have one if you're going to have a production app.

Comment: Heroku lets you add your own TSL certificate or adds one for you. All applications with paid dynos include Automated Certificate Management for free. After adding a certificate in Heroku app > Settings it works fine.